# Why object does not see his method?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am developing a game using the framework atomJS and library libCanvas. Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
var Planet=atom.Class({
//other code
clearLayer : function (layer) {
        layer.ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    },
colonize : function (layer, angle, color,ms) {
        **this.clearLayer(layer);**
        drawArc({
            context: layer.ctx,
            x: Math.round(this.x + this.size / 2),
            y: Math.round(this.y + this.size / 2),
            radius: this.radius + 5,
            width: 4,
            color: color,
            opacity: 0.6,
            angleFinish: angle
        });
        if (this.colonizing) {
            //if (this.cursorOnPlanet()) this.context.fillText(COLONIZING, (this.x + this.size / 2) - 30, this.y + this.size - 2);
            this.colonizingTimer = setTimeout(this.colonize, ms,layer, angle + 5, color,ms);
            if (angle > 360) {
                this.colonizing = false;
                this.state = 1;
            }
        } else {
            clearTimeout(this.colonizingTimer);
            this.clearLayer(layer);
        }
    },
});
```

On this line, `this.clearLayer(layer);` the script terminates with an error `Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'clearLayer'`.Tell me please what's the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to see how `whateverObject.colonize()` is actually getting called. Anyway, it's clear that the original object's method is being bound to a different object before getting called. This is fairly common in event handlers, for example, where `this` usually (but not always) ends up being the event target, not the method's original object.

It's common for developers to use a closure to ensure that they have a safe reference for the original `this`. For example, you might define `colonize` in a constructor that says `var self=this;`, which would guarantee the name `self` points to the original `this` even if `this` itself gets rebound.

Another approach is to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (which you'd have to polyfill for old JS engines), which creates a new function with a `this` object guaranteed to be whatever you specify.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the function is being called from the DOM window and not the local class. When the `this` object is a window, you'll inevitably have scoping issues.

Your problem is with the `setTimeout` function. When the timeout is called, it's telling the `DOMWindow`, not the local class, to call the function. To fix this, wrap the call into a function.
`function(){<code>}`

Edit: I'm not really sure of the purpose of the extra fields in the setTimeout, so I omitted my solution. If you wrap whatever you're doing in a function, it should work though.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
this.colonizingTimer = setTimeout(this.colonize, ms,layer, angle + 5, color,ms);
```

to

```
var self = this;
this.colonizingTimer = setTimeout(function(){self.colonize.call(self);}, ms,layer, angle + 5, color,ms);
```

The thing is that because of the timeout, the `this` object is removed from your object scope and at execution time refers to the global object(`window`) which has no method named `clearLayer`.

#### Here's a [simplified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/W7W3n/) to see the difference.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference since self is equal to this at the point it is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

& the most correct way is to use "delay":

```
this.colonizingTimer = this.colonize.delay(ms, this, [layer, angle + 5, color, ms]);
```

But, if i understand right you want to animate angle from zero to 360 degrees? Why dont you use "Animatable" & ".animate" ?

With every question about LibCanvas you can send me an email to shocksilien@gmail.com